# How to display data from Rails 5 API in React.js frontend app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs, rails-api

I have set up an API with Rails, with a `http://localhost:3001/api/words` endpoint exposing the following data:

```
[{"id":1,"term":"Reach","definition":"Reach is the number of people who had any content from your Page or about your Page enter their screen.","example":"","author":"Loomly","credit":"https://www.loomly.com/","created_at":"2018-11-02T03:21:20.718Z","updated_at":"2018-11-02T03:21:20.718Z"},{"id":2,"term":"Emoji","definition":"A small digital image or icon used to express an idea, emotion, etc., in electronic communication","example":"","author":"Loomly","credit":"https://www.loomly.com/","created_at":"2018-11-02T03:23:50.595Z","updated_at":"2018-11-02T03:23:50.595Z"}]
```

I am now trying to simply display this data (ideally as an unordered list) in a React.js frontend application built with `Create React App`, and here is the content of my `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {}
    this.getWords = this.getWords.bind(this)
    this.getWord = this.getWord.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.getWords()
  }

  fetch (endpoint) {
    return window.fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  getWords () {
    this.fetch('/api/words')
      .then(words => {
        if (words.length) {
          this.setState({words: words})
          this.getWord(words[0].id)
        } else {
          this.setState({words: []})
        }
      })
  }

  getWord (id) {
    this.fetch(`/api/words/${id}`)
      .then(word => this.setState({word: word}))
  }

  render () {
    let {words, word} = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(words).map((key) => {
          return (
            <div key={word.id}>
              <p>{word.term}</p>;
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I believe the problem is located in the following area of the code:

```
render () {
  let {words, word} = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(words).map((key) => {
          return (
            <div key={word.id}>
              <p>{word.term}</p>;
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried to follow the steps explained in [this tutorial](https://blog.heroku.com/a-rock-solid-modern-web-stack), as well as in [that other tutorial](https://medium.com/@bruno_boehm/reactjs-ruby-on-rails-api-heroku-app-2645c93f0814), while keeping the layout of the page as simple as possible (no bells & whistles from `semantic-ui-css`), and no matter what I try, I keep getting into of the following errors:

- `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`
- `Unexpected token, expected “,”`
- `Failed to compile: 'word' is not defined  no-undef`

The solution explained in [this article](https://kirstyburgoine.wordpress.com/2018/01/21/iterating-through-json-data-in-react/) led me to the code I have now, but there is something I am missing about the way to structure my React app: can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: At the beginning `this.state` is empty object, so `words` and `word` in `render` are `undefined`. Also from given info `words` seems to be an array, so keys would represent index. Does `/api/words/${id}` return different data than you have in `words[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

```html
getWords () {    
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/words')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // console.log(res); you should get the response you mentioned
    this.setState({words: res});
  });
}
```

Then check Are you getting data in your state by consoling it.

Then you can work on it using following

```html
render{
 return(
   <div>
     { this.state.words.map((val) => (
         <span>{val.term}</span>
     ))}
   </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `let {words, word} = this.state`;
`this.state` doesnt have word property yet. You could initialize `this.state` like this:

```
this.state = {
   words: [],
   word: {}
};
```

be free to ask

Comment: Evgeniy Boytsov thanks a lot, that contributed to solving the issue related to words and word being undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code in the question:

1. `words` & `word` are not defined.
2. Iteration through `words` in the `render()` function was not set properly with `keys`.

Thanks to the answers and comments left on this question, here is the code I ended up using:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      words : [],
      word : {}
    }
    this.getWords = this.getWords.bind(this)
    this.getWord = this.getWord.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.getWords()
  }

  fetch (endpoint) {
    return window.fetch(endpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  getWords () {
    this.fetch('/api/words')
      .then(words => {
        if (words.length) {
          this.setState({words: words})
          this.getWord(words[0].id)
        } else {
          this.setState({words: []})
        }
      })
  }

  getWord (id) {
    this.fetch(`/api/words/${id}`)
      .then(word => this.setState({word: word}))
  }

  render () {
    let {words} = this.state
    return (
      <ul className="words-container">
        {Object.keys(words).map((key) => {
          return (
            <li className="word-container" key={key}>
              {words[key].term}: {words[key].definition}.
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```